# Reset tkinter radiobuttons created in for loop to default value

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating radiobuttons within a for loop.  I want to be able to reset all their values with a single button (basically start the survey again from scratch), so I created 'self.info.buttons = []' and have appended each radiobutton to this list.  However when I try and reset to the default value '-1' for unanswered, it results in the first & fourth option being selected and messes up the grouping.

```
def askQuestions(self):
    file = open('questions.txt')
    questionlist = file.readlines()
    for number, question in enumerate(questionlist, 1):
        self.var = tk.IntVar(value = -1)
        width = 5
        line = '{:5}'.format(number, fill=' ') + ' : ' + question.strip()
        label = tk.Label(self, text=line)
        label.grid(row=number, column = 0, sticky=tk.W)
        options = ['?', 'No', 'Maybe', 'Yes']
        for answer in range(-1,3):
            button = tk.Radiobutton(self, borderwidth=10, variable = self.var, text=options[answer+1], width = 5, value = answer, indicatoron=0)
            button.grid(row = number, column = answer+2)
        self.info.buttons.append(button) # List containing radiobuttons
        self.info.answers.append(self.var)
```

...function which resets values ....

Inside a class called Info() :

```
 def resetFields(self):
    self.name.set(value = '') #these work
    self.dob.set(value = '')
    for count, button in enumerate(self.buttons): 
        self.buttons[count].config(value = -1) # nothing I have tried works.
```

I have not been programming Python, or Tkinter long and it is probably a rudimentary mistake, but I have tried everything I can think of.  The source is available here : https://github.com/inyoka/sand
Perhaps I should have just 'destroy'ed the form and recreated it? Resetting the variables seemed the simpler option when I started.  Any help gratefully recieved.

Comment: The self.buttons is inside the 'info' class, the other function is in a desperate class so I access it using self.info.buttons.  I will edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `self.buttons` you have `Button()` objects which don't keep answers. You have answers in `IntVar()` objects which are in `self.answers`. So you have to reset `self.answers`.

BTW: you don't have to use `enumerate`

```
def resetFields(self):
    self.name.set(value='')
    self.dob.set(value='')

    for a in self.answers:
        a.set(value=-1)
```

When you reset `self.answers` then `buttons` change state too.

Comment: Awesome, it now works.  I think the longer I worked on this the further from a solution I was.  Thank you I really appreciate your help.