# How to set values for Radiobuttons values to default which were created through a loop in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have looked into a similar post as mine [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40827484/12199232) but setting value to 0 does not work. I have also tried `self.Btna.select()`

I copied this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58329840/12199232) but amended it to my needs.

```
     self.vars = []
     for idx,i in enumerate(self.info):
         self.var = IntVar(value=0)
         self.vars.append(self.var)
         self.lblOption = Label(main,text=i)
         self.btnYes = Radiobutton(main, text="Yes", variable=self.var, value=2)
         self.btnNo = Radiobutton(main, text="No", variable=self.var, value=1)
         self.btnNa = Radiobutton(main, text="N/A", variable=self.var,value=0)
         self.lblOption.grid(column=1,row=idx, sticky = E)
         self.btnYes.grid(column=2,row=idx)
         self.btnNo.grid(column=3,row=idx)
         self.btnNa.grid(column=4,row=idx)
```

this creates me a nice smooth radiobuttons along with some labels. But I am trying to reset all values back to `N/A` if some where selected as `yes` or `no`.

I have tried `self.Btna.select()` but that deselects the last item on the list but not all.

Also, tried the following:

```
        for a in self.btnNa:
                a.select()
```

with an error of:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the value of `variable` of radiobutton to change its value.

Try,

```
for intvar in self.vars:
    intvar.set(0)
```

This should reset all back to value 0 which is `"N/A"`.